# kernel 4.19: replacement for dentry_update_name_case()?

Tags: linux, kernel

In 4.19 the `dentry_update_name_case` function was [removed](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=v4.19.1&id=63a67a926e214dac94e29147c0f3d11499f655a1).

What's the replacement for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no replacement; the function was removed because its user, `ncpfs`, had been removed (as you know only too well). If you’re working on restoring `ncpfs`, I would consider adding the function locally in `ncpfs`.

Comment: Hey. I do not see that this function was part of ncpfs. I think the function was part of kernel in file fs/dcache.c b/fs/dcache.c . This file is not ncpfs.

Comment: I didn’t say that it was part of `ncpfs`. It was used by `ncpfs` and nothing else; so instead of looking for a replacement, you could restore it, and to keep things “grouped together”, do so in `ncpfs` rather than the dcache.

Comment: Ok. Will do so. Just does't want to double the functionality if there maybe was an alternative function.